# Divide axes.table multiindex into different columns

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a crosstab with multiple index which I need to print on pdf.
I am using matplotlib for printing data on pdf and am not able to find any method which helps print dataframe directly to pdf.
So using axes.table to convert dataframe to table to be printed on pdf.
However, the 2 indexes in dataframe are combined in 1 in table. 
See output below

[image]

Can these indexes ('ABC', 'D') separated in 2 columns like ABC | D .
If Yes, how?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
import pandas as pd

pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("test.pdf")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=0.2,width_ratios=[14, 6])
plt.autoscale()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0 ,0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 1])
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['ABC','PQR','XYZ','ABC','PQR'], 'region': ['D','E','F','D','F'], 'month_day':[1,1,1,2,3],'sales' : [100,200,300,500,100]})
table=pd.pivot_table(df, values='sales', index=['country','region'], columns=['month_day'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)

#for printing on pdf
the_table = ax0.table(cellText=table.values,colLabels=table.columns,rowLabels=table.index,loc='center')

pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
pdf.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution after few tries.
table.reset_index(inplace=True)
worked in this case.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf
import pandas as pd

pdf = matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf.PdfPages("test.pdf")

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 20))
grid = plt.GridSpec(1, 2, wspace=0.2,width_ratios=[14, 6])
plt.autoscale()
ax0 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0 ,0])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(grid[0, 1])
df = pd.DataFrame({'country': ['ABC','PQR','XYZ','ABC','PQR'], 'region': ['D','E','F','D','F'], 'month_day':[1,1,1,2,3],'sales' : [100,200,300,500,100]})
table=pd.pivot_table(df, values='sales', index=['country','region'], columns=['month_day'], aggfunc=sum, fill_value=0)
table.reset_index(inplace=True)
the_table = ax0.table(cellText=table.values,colLabels=table.columns,colWidths=[0.07,0.06,0.04,0.04,0.04],loc='center')
ax0.axis("off")
ax1.axis("off")
plt.axis("off")
pdf.savefig(fig, bbox_inches='tight')
pdf.close()
```

[image]